# Is there a way to show a 2D projection on a 3D point clouds scatter plot using scatter3?

Tags: matlab

I use scatter3 function to plot a 3D points cloud results. And now I want to plot a 2D projection of the scatter points onto, for example, Y-Z plane.

The ideal result should be the scattered points cloud in a 3D matrix as well as the 2D projection on the Y-Z plane. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just set all the elements of X,Y, or Z to a single value, that will project all the points to that plane. I projected to the X = 1 plane because it's behind the plot and looks better.

```
Points = rand(50,3);
scatter3(Points(:,1),Points(:,2),Points(:,3),'.');
hold on
scatter3(ones(size(Points(:,1))),Points(:,2),Points(:,3),'+')
hold off
```

Comment: Thanks! I successfully use this method to plot the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script that does something like what you're looking for

```
% generate random data
n = 64;
x = zeros(n,3);
for k = 1:3
    x(:,k) = randi(4) * randn(n,1) + randi(8);
end
x(:,4) = randi([8,16],n,1);
x(:,5) = randi(256,n,1);

% generate scatter plot
h = scatter3(x(:,1),x(:,2),x(:,3),x(:,4),x(:,5));
h.MarkerFaceColor = 'flat';

% get axes handle
hAx = gca;
hAx.XLabel.String = 'x';
hAx.YLabel.String = 'y';
hAx.ZLabel.String = 'z';

% get axes slices
xSlice = hAx.XLim(2);
ySlice = hAx.YLim(2);
zSlice = hAx.ZLim(1);

% add projected markers
hAx.NextPlot = 'add';
hAx.Box = 'on';
% xy plane
h(2) = scatter3(x(:,1),x(:,2),zSlice*ones(n,1),x(:,4),x(:,5));
% zy plane
h(2) = scatter3(xSlice*ones(n,1),x(:,2),x(:,3),x(:,4),x(:,5));
% xz plane
h(3) = scatter3(x(:,1),ySlice*ones(n,1),x(:,3),x(:,4),x(:,5));
view(-45,30)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!